# Sub Domain with different ports in Plesk

Tags: subdomain, hosting, plesk

I am new to Plesk ( and virtual servers in general ). I have a server running CentOS and Plesk 12 and my domain and web site are working perfectly. At present I also have an instance of Dreamfactory running on port 82 (so access it at `http://example.com:81` ) but I wondered if it were possible to setup a subdomain with plesk such as `http://api.example.com` that would load my dream factory instance without forwarding to `http://example.com:81` (effectively masking the port number).

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open sub-domain's "Apache & nginx Settings" and add into "Additional directives for HTTP":

```
# for Apache
ProxyPass / http://example.com:81/
```

Or

```
# for Nginx
location ~ / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://example.com:81;
}
```

[image: plesk sub domain different port]

Like this for Apache:
[image: plesk sub domain different port]

Or like this for nginx:
[image: plesk sub domain different port]

Comment: @MarkusStreicher could you please provide some details what exactly doesn't work? There maybe mismatch in host header, or maybe other web server directives override this customization, at the end it's a just an nginx config.

Comment: Not sure if my question is entirely related, but for the same subdomain can different applications be accessed on different ports? i.e. handle API requests (Port 80) in a Laravel application and for port 5683 handle them in a Node JS application.

Comment: @LukeGalea add nginx directive did the tricks, you can set the directives for each domain.

Comment: @Oleg Neumyvakin,  is this solution work on windows server?

Comment: @ZakariyaPindhariya Actually, not sure that it's possible for Windows, but I've not seen modern Plesk for several years. so some new settings may apear.